# .htaccess best practices for Laravel application folders in subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

My hosting service does not allow the creation of folders outside the public (`www/`) directory. However, for subdomains it automatically creates folders outside `www/`, for example `laravel/`.

I copied the content of my Laravel 4 app's `public/` folder into `www/` and the rest into the `laravel/` folder, adjusted paths, etc. so the site works, but I don't want to inadvertently serve anything from `laravel.mydomain.com`.

What are the best practices in .htaccess, `deny from all` or a simple `Redirect 301 / mydomain.com`?
I guess a redirect exposes that the subdomain exists, so it may not be ideal. Any issues I could have with deny?

Thanks.

EDIT: I went with `Redirect 301 / http://mydomain.foo` in a `.htaccess` file that resides in the folder where the non-public files of the Laravel app are and which Apache serves `laravel.mydomain.foo` from. `mydomain.foo` is served from the standard location the hosting service provides and contains the public files. One year down the line it has not bitten me yet. The question is still open if someone has a better approach.

Comment: Would be cool to get an answer on this.

Comment: This post is old and unanswered whereas it's really a good question.
If @hlev has the answer, share it please.

Comment: @KeizerBridge thanks for asking, I edited the question.